I need help drawing this electrical circuit with circuitikz
I'm new on Circuitikz. So, I need some help on drawing a little circuit for a lab report. I'd  really appreciate if someone helps me. This is the circuit:

I managed to do this:
\begin{circuitikz}
    % Variable Voltage Source
    \draw (0,0) to[american voltage source, v=$V_s$] (0,3);
    
    % Draw node
    \node at (1,3) [circle, draw, fill=black, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt] {};
    
    % Connect to node
    \draw (0,3) to[short] (1,3);

    % Open circuit
    \draw (1,4) -- (2,3) to[short, *-*] (2,3);
    
    % Ammeter
    \draw (2,3) -- (2.5,3) to[ammeter, l=A] (4,3) -- (5,3);
    
    \draw (5,3) -- (5,0);
      
    \draw (0,0) to[short] (0,-2);

    \draw (0,-2) to[voltmeter] (5,-2);

    \draw (5,0) to[short] (5,-2);

    \draw (0,0) to[lamp, *-*] (5,0);
\end{circuitikz}

And this is the output:

Is this oK? Or could be improved?

Can you show us what you've got so far? What's the problem you're having exactly? Start with an example from this site or the documentation and try to modify it to your needs. You can use texdoc or find the manual for the package online.

That is not an MWE, but well... see my answer and do the same when asking your next question.

Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see How do you accept an answer?). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

I would use this code: if you go through the examples in the tutorial part of the manual, you will see the advantages in using relative coordinates, named coordinates, and the perpendicular "trick" -| and |-.
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
% always select a type of voltage orientation
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    % Variable Voltage Source
    % you are using an american symbol with european (arrow) voltage notation, without
    % specifying a direction style. Avoid the horrible double marking of the voltage
    % better use relative movements, name the generator for future reference
    \draw (0,0) coordinate(start)
        to[american voltage source, l=$V_s$, name=vv] ++(0,2)
        % continue the drawing with the switch:
        |- ++(1,1) to[nos=L, *-*] ++(1,0)
        % Ammeter: the newer rmeterwa symbol is, in my opinion, better
        to[rmeterwa, t=A] ++(3,0)
        % move to the same vertical position than start
        coordinate(upper left) -- (upper left |- start)
        % close with the lamp
        coordinate(start lamp) to [lamp, *-*] (start);
    % using one path gives better "corner" junctions, as above.
    % now add the voltmeter
    \draw (start) -- ++(0,-2) coordinate(start v)
        to[rmeterwa, t=V] (start v -| start lamp) -- (start lamp);
    % add a tunable arrow to the generator, to show it's variable
    \ctikztunablearrow[color=gray]{2}{1.2}{-30}{vv}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}


All the numbers in the circuit are relative, and then the connections are made with named coordinates. So, if you decide that the drawing is too wide, you can just change the ++(3,0) of the ammeter to ++(2,0) to have:

without touching any other part of the code.
